# limit inequality proof

Tags: limits

> If $X=(x_n)$ and $Y=(y_n)$ are sequences of real numbers which both
>   converge to $c$ and if $Z=(z_n)$ is a sequence such that $x_n\le
> z_n\le y_n$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then $Z$ also converges to $c$.

What I know is that $\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}(x_n)=c$ and that $\text{lim}_{n\to\infty}(y_n)=c$. Thus I know by the definition of a limit, that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$, $\forall$  $n>N$ such that $$\left|{x_n}-c\right|<\epsilon$$ 
$$\left|{y_n}-c\right|<\epsilon.$$
How can I continue? I know that any subsequence of a convergent sequence must converge. I also know, $x_n\le z_n\le y_n \implies lim(x_n)\le
lim(z_n)\le lim(y_n)$, but I do not know how to incorporate all of this together in completing my proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for any $\varepsilon>0$,  there exists $N$ s.t. if $n>N$ then $|x_n-c|<\varepsilon$, $|y_n-c|<\varepsilon$ for all $n$. So if $n>N$, then
$$c-\varepsilon < x_n<c+\varepsilon$$
and
$$c-\varepsilon <y_n<c+\varepsilon$$
for all $n$. So
$$c-\varepsilon < x_n \le z_n \le y_n < c+\varepsilon$$
and we get
$$|z_n-c|<\varepsilon$$
for all $n>N$.